# Spring mvc uri path matching regular expression

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I was hoping to match the mapping for `/some-slug-1234` in following request mapping but it says no mapping found. What I am doing wrong ?

```
@Controller
public class MyRequestHandlerController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/[^/]+\\-[0-9]+", method = { RequestMethod.HEAD, RequestMethod.GET } )
    public void handleDocument(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
      // render article
    }
 }
```

Comment: It's not clear what do you want, but this regex does not match the given URL. Try: `[/]+[a-z]+[-]+[a-z]+[-]+[1-9]+` instead.

Comment: I have been using this `[^/]+\-[0-9]+` for a while now and it works just fine. Although, I had to escape `\\` in it , see in question above twice \\.

Comment: Can you try using : [^/]+[\w]+\\-+[\w]+\\-[0-9]+$